# Operator Overload << in Linked List

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, linked-list

How can I overload the `operator <<`.
The purpose of the overloaded operator is to do:
`cout << ptr->info` and not receive the memory address but Display the maker year and model of that node's info section.

Example:

```
template <class DataType>
struct Node {
DataType info;
Node<DataType> *next;
};
```

In each info section of the Node there will be a struct like this:

```
struct Car {
    string maker;
    string year;
    string model;
}
```

So far I have this but it doesn't seems to work:

```
friend ostream &operator << ( ostream &output, Node<DataType> &rlist ) { //Overloaded <<
    output << rlist->info.make << endl;
    output << rlist->info.year << endl;
    output << rlist->info.price << endl; 

    return output;
}
```

When I compile with g++ I get this error:

```
LinkedList.cpp: In member function ‘void LinkedList<DataType>::EscribaUltimo() [with DataType = CarType]’:
main.cpp:37:   instantiated from here
LinkedList.cpp:15: error: no match for ‘operator<<’ in ‘std::cout << ptr->Node<CarType>::info’
```

Comment: @Jacob, at least we duel-edited to the same tags :)

Comment: This thing's going to end up community wiki in about 2 more edits...

Comment: @GMan: I was going for operator-overloading :)

Comment: No more edits, I think. Why so many people edited it so many times... who knows.

Comment: Lol, agreed. My cursor shall not darken the `retag` button again!

Answer (score 2):

Although I'm a bit confused, because you're actual main code is missing. I'm going to assume you have a node, from traversing the link, and now want to print it:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std; // not recommended, but useful
                     // in snippets

// T is usually used, but this is of course up to you
template <class T> 
struct Node
{
    typedef T value_type; // a usual typedef

    value_type info;
    Node<value_type> *next;
};

struct Car
{
    string maker;
    string year;
    string model;
}; // you had a missing ;, probably copy-paste error

// this creates a node. normally you'd want this to be
// wrapped into a list class (more on this later)
template <typename T>
Node<T> *createNode(const T& info = T())
{
    // allocate node
    Node<T> *result = new Node<T>;
    result->info = info;
    result->next = 0; // no next

    return result; // returning a pointer means
                   // whoever gets this is
                   // responsible for deleting it!
}

// this is the output function for a node
template <typename T>
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& sink, const Node<T>& node)
{
    // note that we cannot assume what node contains!
    // rather, stream the info attached to the node
    // to the ostream:
    sink << node.info;

    return sink;
}

// this is the output function for a car
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& sink, const Car& car)
{
    // print out car info
    sink << "Make: " << car.maker <<
            "\nYear: " << car.year <<
            "\nModel: " << car.model << std::endl;

    return sink;
}

int main(void)
{
    // a car list
    typedef Node<Car> CarList;

    // a couple cars
    Car car1 = {"Dodge", "2001", "Stratus"};
    Car car2 = {"GMan's Awesome Car Company", "The future", "The best"};

    CarList *head = createNode(car1); // create the first node
    head->next = createNode(car2);

    // now traverse the list
    CarList *iter = head;
    for (; iter != 0; iter = iter->next)
    {
        // output, dereference iterator to get the actual node
        std::cout << "Car: " << *iter << std::endl;
    }

    // dont forget to delete!
    iter = head;
    while (iter)
    {
        // store next
        CarList *next = iter->next;

        // delete and move on
        delete iter;
        iter = next;
    }
}
```

Now, if you don't have to create your own linked list, use the standard link list instead, it simplifies your task immensely:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <list>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

struct Car
{
    string maker;
    string year;
    string model;
};


// this is the output function for a car
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& sink, const Car& car)
{
    // print out car info
    sink << "Make: " << car.maker <<
            "\nYear: " << car.year <<
            "\nModel: " << car.model << std::endl;

    return sink;
}

int main(void)
{
    // a car list
    typedef std::list<Car> CarList;

    // a couple cars
    Car car1 = {"Dodge", "2001", "Stratus"};
    Car car2 = {"GMan's Awesome Car Company", "The future", "The best"};

    CarList cars;
    cars.push_back(car1);
    cars.push_back(car2);

    // now traverse the list (copy to ostream)
    std::copy(cars.begin(), cars.end(),
             std::ostream_iterator<Car>(std::cout,"\n"));

    // delete done automatically in destructor
}
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Just to make sure, you have

```
template<class DataType>
```

before the operator definition, right?  If I do that, it works for me.  The error messages show the line numbers in  your code, but where is it in the pasted definitions?  Reading it, I think the problem isn't with

```
Node<DataType> myNode;
output << myNode
```

but with

```
output << myNode.info
```

which does not have a operator<< defined for it.

Edit:  By your comment, it sounds like you want to define an << operator for the car.  So, I would do (untested)

```
ostream& operator<< (ostream& output, Car& car) {
  output << car.foo << end;
  output << car.bar << end;
  return output;
}

template <class DataType>
ostream& operator<< (ostream& output, Node<DataType>& node ) {
  output << node.info << end;
  return output;
}
```

Basically, what that means is that when you specialize your Node type and wish to use the << operator on it, you need to make sure that the  DataType you are specializing with also has the << operator defined.

Comment: I Don't know how to define an operator << for 
myNode.info. That is exactly what I want to do.

Comment: I find it surprising that it worked for you, given Naveen's (correct) remarks about errors in the accesses to Car, plus that the given operator is, at best, a specialization of a template for Car. Did you *actually* get output, or did it merely compile?

Comment: Martin, what is there to work?  There isn't even a main function.  What I meant was that I took the code Loki provided and got something similar to work.  Sorry for not being precise.

Comment: It's still not clear to me what it is that you got to work (in particular if it's not your /untested/ code). However, it must deviate from the original code in more aspects than just adding the missing template declaration to the operator.

Answer (score 0):

You need two operators: one for Node (or `Node*`), and one for Car:

```
ostream &operator << ( ostream &output, Car &car ) {
    output << car.maker << endl;
    output << car.year << endl;
    output << car.model << endl; 
    return output;
}

template<class DataType>
ostream &operator << ( ostream &output, Node<DataType> *rlist ) {
    output << rlist->info;
    return output;
}
```